# How to install virtualbox guest additions in TrueOS?

Tags: virtualbox, trueos

I have installed TrueOS in Virtualbox. Everything is working perfectly. But after I insert virtualbox guest additions, I am unable to find any way to install it. How can I do so?

I am using Ubuntu host.

Comment: Apparently a solution seems to be switching to full screen. However it is not as comfortable as with guest additions installed. Also in TrueOS official site they have asked to use .vdi.xz file. However I am unable to find any download link anywhere.

Comment: You have to mount the guest additions device and run the installer on the guest.

Answer (score 3):

Go to TrueOS terminal

```
sudo su
cd /var/db/portsnap
portsnap fetch
cd /usr/ports
portsnap extract
portsnap fetch update
git clone https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd.git /usr/src    //This will take about 30 minutes - 1 hour depending upon your internet speed
cd /usr/src; make clean    //This will take about 1 hour
cd /usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions && make install clean    //This will take about 5-6 hours
reboot
```

After reboot adjust screen resolution of TrueOS to the recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Install the virtualbox-ose-additions package from the AppCafe or via `pkg install virtualbox-ose-additions` from a terminal.
I think it installs a kernel module that needs to be loaded and/or a service that needs to be enabled, then restart the VM and at the login screen hit the button in the lower-right corner to change your video driver and make sure you switch to "vboxvideo".

Comment: Why would anyone do it any other way :)

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following commands from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
pkg install virtualbox_ose_additions
Add the following lines to /etc/rc.conf
     vboxguest_enable="YES"
     vboxservice_enable="YES"
reboot
```